# Unexpected response code 500 for POST method, with Volley lib

Tags: android, json, android-volley

My Input Json format is this:

```
 {
  "customerId": "amit@gmail.com",
   "totalAmount": "120",
    "orderJson": [
   {
  "packageId": 3,
  "variantcomponentsJson": [
    {
      "itemId": "3",
      "itemQuantity": "Half"
    },
    {
      "itemId": "4",
      "itemQuantity": "2"
    }
  ],
  "optionalcomponentsJson": {
    "itemPrice": "50",
    "itemId": "5",
    "itemQuantity": "2"
  },
  "quantity": 2
}
 ], "deliveryAddress": {
"id": -1,
"addressName": "my address",
"localityID": 1,
"localityName": "cvraman",
"areaID": 2,
"areaName": "kr puram",
"address": "kr puram railway",
"landMark": "bridge"
 }
}
```

I use Volley Library for Parsing:And My Java Code is like

```
   public static void submitOrder(final PlaceOrderData placeOrderData, final             String authToken, final PlaceOrderCallback callback) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Auth token " + authToken);
    JSONObject jObjPlaceOrder = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jObjPlaceOrder.put("customerId", placeOrderData.getCustomerId());
        jObjPlaceOrder.put("totalAmount", placeOrderData.getTotalAmount());
        JSONArray jArrayOrderJson = new JSONArray();
        for (OrderJson orderJson : placeOrderData.getOrderJson()) {
            JSONObject jOBJOrder = new JSONObject();
            jOBJOrder.put("packageId", orderJson.getPackageId());
            JSONArray jArrayVariantComponentsJson = new JSONArray();
            for (VariantcomponentsJson variantcomponentsJson : orderJson.getVariantcomponentsJson()) {
                JSONObject jOBJVariantcomponentsJson = new JSONObject();
                jOBJVariantcomponentsJson.put("itemId", variantcomponentsJson.getItemId());
                jOBJVariantcomponentsJson.put("itemQuantity", variantcomponentsJson.getItemQuantity());
                jArrayVariantComponentsJson.put(jOBJVariantcomponentsJson);
            }
            OptionalcomponentsJson optionalcomponentsJson = orderJson.getOptionalcomponentsJson();

            JSONObject jOBJOptionalComponentsJson = new JSONObject();
            jOBJOptionalComponentsJson.put("itemPrice", optionalcomponentsJson.getItemPrice());
            jOBJOptionalComponentsJson.put("itemId", optionalcomponentsJson.getItemId());
            jOBJOptionalComponentsJson.put("itemQuantity", optionalcomponentsJson.getItemQuantity());

            jOBJOrder.put("variantcomponentsJson", jArrayVariantComponentsJson);
            jOBJOrder.put("optionalcomponentsJson", jOBJOptionalComponentsJson);
            jOBJOrder.put("quantity", orderJson.getQuantity());
            jArrayOrderJson.put(jOBJOrder);
        }

        jObjPlaceOrder.put("orderJson", jArrayOrderJson);
        DeliveryAddress deliveryAddress = placeOrderData.getDeliveryAddress();

        JSONObject jOBJDeliveryAddress = new JSONObject();
        jOBJDeliveryAddress.put("id", deliveryAddress.getId());
        jOBJDeliveryAddress.put("addressName", deliveryAddress.getAddress());
        jOBJDeliveryAddress.put("localityID", deliveryAddress.getLocalityID());
        jOBJDeliveryAddress.put("localityName", deliveryAddress.getLocalityName());
        jOBJDeliveryAddress.put("areaID", deliveryAddress.getAreaID());
        jOBJDeliveryAddress.put("areaName", deliveryAddress.getAreaName());
        jOBJDeliveryAddress.put("address", deliveryAddress.getAddress());
        jOBJDeliveryAddress.put("landMark", deliveryAddress.getLandMark());

        jObjPlaceOrder.put("deliveryAddress", jOBJDeliveryAddress);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    RequestQueue requestQueue = VolleyRequestProcessor.getInstance().getRequestQueue();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, ApiUrls.URL_POST_PLACE_ORDER, jObjPlaceOrder,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("log_tag", "response" + response.toString());

                }
            }

            , new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            ErrorInfo errorInfo;
            if (networkResponse == null) {
                errorInfo = new ErrorInfo("Unable to reach our servers. Make sure your internet connection works.");
            } else {
                errorInfo = new ErrorInfo(networkResponse.statusCode, "Internal error occurred while communicating with our servers.");
            }
            callback.onFailed(errorInfo);
        }
    }) {


        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

            headers.put(HeaderFields.FIELD_AUTH_TOKEN, authToken);

            return headers;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: what is the error in server side?

Comment: generate message :Unexpected response code 500 for POST method

Comment: I did not find difference between keys names in JSON and code, please check the types of each value, and if it's same in server and client side

Comment: can we take string type for all json key?

Comment: you can convert all types to string, please insert full stack trace of exception

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32709072/httpmediatypenotacceptableexception-httpmediatypenotacceptableexception-could/39871657#39871657