# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException / HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-mvc, controller

I have a API that a client is trying to connect to. However it throws the error:

```
2015 09 22 04:21:44.297 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor] Could not parse Accept header: Invalid token character ',' in token "json,application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
2015 09 22 04:21:44.298 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Resolving exception from handler [public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.areviews.api.restcontroller.APIOrderController.getNewOrderApi(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
2015 09 22 04:21:44.298 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver] Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.areviews.web.controller.AbstractController.handleException(java.lang.Exception,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:129)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"order/add"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json; charset=utf-8")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> getNewOrderApi(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    .....

    return JsonUtils.createJson(jsonObj);
}
```

They use jQuery to request my API:

```
    $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.mywebsite.com/apiv1/order/add",
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json;charset=utf-8");
            },
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success == true){
                    console.log(data);
                }else{
                    console.log("error: " + data.error_description);
                }
            }
        });
```

The problem is in their Request Header the "Content-Type" is:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:zh,zh-TW;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:561
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

We don't know where the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded," comes from (the "," creates the problem because it should be a ";"). What can I do on my side? What can be done on their side?

Comment: If you've since solved this problem, one way of giving back to the community is to post a self-answer below.  See [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) for more details.

Comment: have you tried it from RestClient or postman

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue.

I have tried to hit the API from android using Volley.

There are 2 different Content-Type. One is Request header `Content-Type` and other is Body `Content-Type`. When you initiate a `POST` or `PUT` request from the volley, volley take request header and check for body Content-Type. If body Content-Type is not mentioned, volley will add by itself. Volley combines both the Content-Type and our server was able to accept only one Content-Type. But, as volley combines Content-Type for header and body it become "application/json, application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8".

Here, "`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`" is Content-Type for request body. So, to solve this problem, you can override `getBodyContentType()` method and return null.

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
//return super.getBodyContentType();
    return null;
}
```

Do not use `return ""`. Using `return ""` will also throw exception.

```
[org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor] Could not parse Accept header: Invalid token character ',' in token "json, "
```

Hope this will help.